# How can I create a div with maximize and minimize functionality using angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create a div with maximize and minimize functionality using angular.
There is a maximize icon on default, on clicking that button the div should be maximize and icon should changed to minimize. on clicking minimize icon it should minimize and the icon reverted to maximize.

Comment: a ngb-accordion https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples or a mat-expansion-pannel https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview ? or you want make yourself? (in this case it's only  has a variable toogle and use a *ngIf)

Comment: That is accordion na. I need similer function as minimize and maximize

Comment: You could create a function that modify the width and height of that div based on a condition (`isMinimized` for example).

Answer (score 4):

Define a variable toogle in your ts

```
toogle:boolean=false;
```

And

```
<button (click)="toogle=!toogle"><span>{{toogle?'v':'^'}}</span></button>
<div class="div" [style.height]="toogle?'10rem':'20rem'">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

You can use also [style.min-height]

**Update** You can also

```
<div class="div" [style.height]="toogle?'1.5rem':'100vh'">
  <button (click)="toogle=!toogle"><span>{{toogle?'v':'^'}}</span>
  </button>
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

**Update 2**
If we defined two styles in .ts

```
  toogle:boolean=true;
  minimize= {height:'1.5rem',position:'fixed',bottom:0,overflow:'hidden'}
  maximize={height:'100vh'}
```

We can use:

```
<div class="div" 
    [ngStyle]="toogle?minimize:maximize">
  <button (click)="toogle=!toogle"><span>{{toogle?'v':'^'}}</span></button>lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but this code is working as an accordion.

Comment: when user maximize the div should expand to full window size, and if minimize it should minimze.

Comment: similer to minimize and maximize button in browsers and file explorer and all. colud you help for that plz.

Comment: it's only "play" with [style] using css, I updated my answer, I hope help you